# Ctype casting to Decimal returning negative value

Tags: vb.net, casting, decimal, type-conversion, ctype

I am wondering if this is a bug. Can't understand why would CType work this way...!

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you've put a link to a screenshot, rather than simply copying your code into the question??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because enclosing a value in `()` means it is a negative number.

It is a standard financial notation for amounts that are deducted.

When a number is parsed, if `NumberStyles.AllowParentheses` is set for `NumberStyles`, then they will be interpreted as a negative value.

See [Parsing numeric strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w.aspx) on MSDN:

> NumberStyles.AllowParentheses
>
> Parentheses can be used to indicate negative values.